# Regex to remove prefix and append suffix

Tags: php, regex

I have a string like this:

```
prefix_foobar
```

I'd like to remove the 'prefix_' portion and append a '_suffix' on the end.

```
foobar_suffix
```

Is it possible to do this in PHP by calling preg_replace only once?

It's easy enough to write a pattern to remove the 'prefix_' and replace it with '' but I'm struggling with how to append to the end.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you can do:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/prefix_(.+)(?<!_suffix)$/', '${1}_suffix', $input);
```

**Negative lookbehind** `(?<!_suffix)` is to avoid adding suffix when it is already there.

#### [RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/oF4yX5/1)

Answer (score 2):

How about:

```
$output = preg_replace('/prefix_(.*?)/', "$1_suffix", $input);
```

Answer (score 2):

Personally I would do:

```
$var = 'prefix_koko';

echo ltrim($var, 'prefix_').'_my_suffix';
```

Comment: nice basic thought, but `ltrim()` not good idea in case input like `$var = 'preppprefix_koko';` then it will be failed

Comment: a yes, i use it only when I am foreaching my own declared varaibles, otherwise i would go for some secure regex i guess